# i need the steps to run a code in clojure language contains GUI in java

Tags: clojure

i have a big problem my doctor want form me to make calculator using new language(clojure)but i don't know anything about it i read some information from www.clojure.org but i still have a problem how to save the code in a file to run it another time and i need the path how to connect java to clojure i found this code :

```
(ns rayne.main 
  (:gen-class) 
  (:import (javax.swing JFrame JTextField JButton JOptionPane) 
           (java.awt.event ActionListener) 
           (java.awt GridLayout))) 

(def numbers (ref [])) 
(def times-clicked (ref 0)) 

(defn calc [nseq op] 
  (let [n1 (first nseq) 
       n2 (last nseq)] 
  (cond 
     (= op "+") (+ n1 n2) 
     (= op "*") (* n1 n2) 
     (= op "-") (- n2 n1) 
     (= op "/") (/ n1 n2)))) 

(defn add-op-button [op text button] 
   (.addActionListener button 
    (proxy [ActionListener] [] 
      (actionPerformed [e] 
      (dosync 
       (ref-set times-clicked (inc @times-clicked)) 
       (if (= @times-clicked 2) 
         (do 
         (let [result (.toString (calc @numbers op)) 
               result2 (read-string result)] 
           (.setText text result) 
           (ref-set numbers []) 
           (ref-set times-clicked 0))) 
       (do 
         (ref-set numbers (conj @numbers (read-string (.getText text)))) 
         (.setText text "")))))))) 

(defn -main [] 
  (let [frame (JFrame. "Calculator") 
        add-button (JButton. "+") 
        sub-button (JButton. "-") 
        mul-button (JButton. "*") 
        div-button (JButton. "/") 
        clr-button (JButton. "Clear") 
        text-field (JTextField.)] 
    (add-op-button "+" text-field add-button) 
    (add-op-button "-" text-field sub-button) 
    (add-op-button "*" text-field mul-button) 
    (add-op-button "/" text-field div-button) 
(doto frame 
   (.setLayout (GridLayout. 1 5)) 
  (.add text-field) 
  (.add add-button) 
  (.add sub-button) 
  (.add mul-button) 
  (.add div-button) 
  (.setSize 500 100) 
  (.setVisible true))))
```

so when i try to test it i don't know how it work .
please i need some one to help me in this problem and send me a link to install a clojure program to execute such a file.
thank's for all

Comment: Indent code by four spaces to make it format right

Comment: I could not understand the question, can someone who understands the question edit the English?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a great reason to lean a fun new language.

for getting started with new clojure pojects the *leiningen* tool can get you to the point of compiling and running code very quickly. (i'm assuming mac or linux here)

- install [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen)
- lein new project-name
- put your code in the project-name/src/ ... /core.clj file
- lein uberjar
- java -jar name-of-jar-file
- repeat, hack, and have some fun!

Leiningen can also start a repl for you which will speed up you iterations and integrates well (through slime/swank) with emacs.

[here is a good tutorial on leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md)

Comment: thanks for your help but the problem that i need a program that work on windows operating system not lunix or sun:S.I think leiningen work on lunix not windows operating system:(right?

Answer (score 1):

Clojure.org has a nice section called [Getting Started](http://clojure.org/getting_started) that is about ... getting started. From getting the clojure zip file to debugging and profiling. Very, very basic.

Also has links to more advanced resources.

Comment: thanks alot,i enter this page but i don't understand what did they means by clojure zip file?can you help me

Comment: This is what you would download from here: http://clojure.org/downloads . The actual link to the latest stable clojure release is http://github.com/downloads/clojure/clojure/clojure-1.2.0.zip